# copy a file from wsl to hdfs running on docker

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to copy a file from my local drive to hdfs.

I'm running Hadoop on docker as an image. I try to perform some exercise on MapReduce, therefore, I want to copy a data file from a local drive (let's say my d: drive) to hdfs.

i tried below command but it fails with `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`:

```
scp -P 50070 /mnt/d/project/recreate.out root@localhost:/root
```

since I'm new to Hadoop and big data my explanation may terrible. Please tolerate with me.

I'm trying to do above things from windows subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Regards, 
crf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCP won't move data to Hadoop. And port 50070 is not accepting connections over that protocol (SSH)

You need to setup and use a command similar to `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal`.  You can install the HDFS cli on the Windows host command prompt, too, so you don't need WSL to upload files...

---

When using Docker, I would suggest doing this

1. Add a volume mount from your host to some Hadoop container **outside of** the datanode and namenode directories (in other words, don't override the data that is there, and mounting files here will not "upload to HDFS")
2. `docker exec` into this running container
3. Run above `hdfs` command, uploading from the mounted volume